# Como uso password_hash no select

Tags: php, pdo, hash

Como faço login com a senha toda criptografada ?
Usei `password_hash` e agora pra mim fazer o login como eu faço ?

```
if(isset($_POST['loggin']))
{
    $user                = trim(strip_tags($_POST['user']));
    $txtpassword         = $_POST['password'];

    $select = "SELECT id, user, password FROM users WHERE BINARY user=:user";

    $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
    $result->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
    if($result->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $show = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $idSession      = $show['id'];
        $passwordHash   = $show['password'];
    }

    if (password_verify($txtpassword, $passwordHash))
    {
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $idSession;
        header("Location: ?p=home");
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language= "javascript">
        location.href="?p=sign_in&action=error_sign_in";
        </script>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busque primeiro a senha no banco utilizando o login do usuário, depois verifique:

```
$senhaPost = $_POST['password']; 
$senhaDB = ...; 

if (password_verify($senhaPost, $senhaDB)) { ... }
```

Comment: Onde vou por esse 'if' ai

Comment: @WilliamAlvares  no lugar onde você quer verificar se a senha bate ou não com a do banco. Isso aí já deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Seu código irá mudar bastante, seguindo sua lógica, seria onde acontece o redirecionamento caso o usuário seja legítimo ou não. Substituiria a partir de onde começa seu condicional 'if($count == 1)...'.

Comment: @fabianophp editei o post olha lá como eu fiz.. ainda sim da um erro que não conseguiu ver

Comment: Ah o erro que dá é a passwordHash, n vai ter nada por que o usuario n ta logado.. q burrice minha..

Comment: Beleza, consegui

Comment: @WilliamAlvares Que bom. Não esqueça de aceita-la como resposta correta para sua dúvida.